# How to open a username protected workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I just encountered a very funny incident, which I wrote a VBA code to lock myself out of my workbook. This happened when I was learning how to limit the access to a workbook. The VBA code used are the following VBA code:

```
If environ("username")="xy" Then
msgbox"welcome to the workbook"
Else 
msgbox"You are not authorized to the workbook"
End if
```

My actual username is yx. Therefore I locked myself out and not able to open the workbook again! In the tutorial, the tutor breaks in by using control+pause. However, this does not work in my case! I am wondering if there is other ways. Many thanks!

Comment: Disable macros and then open the workbook so that your on open code doesn't run.  Then you can access the VBA project and correct the code.  Here's hoping you didn't password protect your VBA project.

Comment: Also note that anybody could disable macros and then the code wouldn't run.  Trying to protect a workbook with VBA is notoriously insecure.

Comment: Hold down shift while opening the workbook.

Comment: @TimWilliams, it seems not working.. could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @tigeravatar Could you elaborate more about how to disable the macros? I disabled the developer function. I also tried to do it through Trust Center, but I still cannot open the workbook, with either xlsx or xlsm extention. Thank you

Comment: Excel Options >> Trust Center >> Trust center settings >> Macro settings >> Disable all macros without notification

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you very much Tim. I followed the process, but the Macro is still running when I open the workbook.

Comment: Then something else is going on and we're missing some information here

Comment: @TimWilliams, you are completely right! I tried once again with the same code as I posted and followed your suggestion. It works! In the previous workbook, there must be something else, which is not accessible.